# Differences in Punctuation in Quran

Tags: quran

I was reciting the holy quran and at the same time I was checking my recitation by following the recitation of a famous reciter with the verse showing the in screen in youtube. And I found some differences in punctuations usage between the Quran I am reading from and the one from the youtube. Moreover, I saw some extra punctuation in the one I was reading from. Is there different permitted system or style regarding punctuation in different zone or what is the reason??

I have given two instances spotting the differences in red ink in picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdoZh.jpg)

Comment: The qur'an in its original form had no punctuation. For more details we may need more information (pictures?).

Comment: Now I gave pictures...

Comment: "Punctuation" as you call it is simply made by the scholars to give lay people who don't understand Arabic recommendations on where they can stop in a verse without changing any meaning. It isn't part of the text itself.